# DQL match new users groups to existing users groups

Tags: dql, documentum

I'm trying to use DQL to match a new user groups to an existing users. I've tried the below which doesn't return a error but also doesn't seem to work.

```
UPDATE dm_group objects append users_names='user2' where group_name in (SELECT DISTINCT group_name FROM dm_group WHERE ANY i_all_users_names='user1');
```

Comment: looks like you're trying to add user top groups where another user already is. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE dm_group OBJECTS 
APPEND users_names = ‘user2’ 
WHERE group_name IN 
(SELECT group_name FROM dm_group WHERE ANY users_names IN (‘user1’))
```

If you want to add users to single group you should go with this DQL

```
ALTER GROUP <group_name>
ADD (SELECT user_name FROM dm_user WHERE user_name IN (‘user1’, ‘user2’))
```

I haven't tried DQLs but composed them based on [this page](https://documentumdcm.wordpress.com/dql-queries/groups-dql/). They should work though, if there is a problem please comment my answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I changed the end part, Im not sure if it made any difference though.  users_names = ‘user1’)

Comment: Noration `users_names IN (‘user1’)` is identical to to `users_names = ‘user1’`. However real use of using `IN` keyword is when having set of multiple values like in second DQL: `user_name IN (‘user1’, ‘user2’)`